# WebApi. Custom route not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to add custom route to the controller with `[RoutePrefix("front")]` that contains three methods:

```
[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(SparePartsFrontDTO))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    ...
}

[HttpGet]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<SparePartSearchDTO>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string filter)
{
    ...
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("categories")]
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<DeviceCategoryDTO>))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCategories()
{
    ...
}
```

But when I'm calling method by the route `api/front/categories`, instead of the custom route, default get method was called.

Here is WebApi config:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new PreflightRequestsHandler());
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();    
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The route prefix needs to have the desired template plus the other actions need `Route` attribute as well.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/front")]
public class MyController : ApiController {

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] // matches GET api/front
    [ResponseType(typeof(SparePartsFrontDTO))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() {
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("filter/{filter}")] // matches GET api/front/filter/anything-here
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<SparePartSearchDTO>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get(string filter) {
        //...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("categories")] //matches GET api/front/categories
    [ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<DeviceCategoryDTO>))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetCategories() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Reference [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2 : Route Prefixes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-prefixes)

Comment: I got error saying An error occurred while trying to create a controller like "FrontController". Make sure that the controller has a public constructor with no parameters.

Comment: @andrey.shedko, That is a standard error that happens while the framework is trying to create controller and encounters an issue. If you are using dependency injection (IDependencyResolver) then you need to make sure that all the dependencies have been properly registered with your DI container.

Comment: yes. I'm using DI but I believe that it's not related, beacuse there wasn't problem with DI before I try to create custom route.